# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve : typescript - webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

Built a typescript project which is working fine in my machine (MAC). But when executing the same command in AWS-ec2 instance, build is failing with following error.

> TS2307: Cannot find module './Persons' or its corresponding type
> declarations.
>
> TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'.

Bit strange and unable to figure out the reason.

Based on similar issues, I already added the following to webpack config

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
  }
```

```
Node version :v15.14.0
npm version :7.7.6
webpack : ^4.43.0
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix the issue. The issue is due to the import statement (which worked in the local environment, but failed in AWS-ec2 environment).

Created file 'persons.ts' and defined a class Persons inside this file. The import statement should be

`import {Persons} from './persons'`

But as I use VSC, it takes care of import statement. In this case it imported as

`import {Persons} from './Persons'`

After fixing the import statement (Persons to persons) the application is up.